# Should I use "once I have" or "once I had" in this type of sentence?

Tags: tense

I have a question here and I'm not sure which one to use since they both seem correct, the question goes like this.

> once I ... this novel, I'll give it to my old friend".

In place of ellipsis (...), should I use:

(A) have read
or
(B) had read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Have read" is correct. Everything in the sentence is taking place in the future. You might be misled because the word "once" sometimes suggests the past, like "once upon a time", but in this sentence you could replace it with "when."

The timeline will look like:

- Right this second, I'm saying this sentence
- Some time later I'll finish the novel
- *After that*—maybe even immediately after—I can say that I "have read" the novel, and will give it away.

Comment: Andy, my profound apologies! I was editing your answer to change **be mislead** to **be misled** when I somehow managed to delete it (my first such error in many years on the site). Will you kindly repeat it. I am very sorry.

Comment: @RonaldSole Actually, it looks ok to me! (And thanks for correcting an embarrassing mistake!)